# How to change div background color based on what the user does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say i have the following code

```
<body>
<div class = "header">Header content</div>
<div class = "content">content</div>


</body>
```

How can i make the header div hide when the user is going down on the website and show up when going up? Similar to this website https://www.kohactive.com/

Comment: Refer this link https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c#.n4pt2d8bv

Answer (score 1):

you can use JQuery's scrolltop function, i.e.  `$(document).scrollTop();` to get the current position of the scrollbar, and pair it with a function to do certain behaviour, i.e.

```
var windowPosY = $(this).scrollTop();

if(windowPosY >= 500 //500 pixels)
{
    //Hide the header here, using an animation or setting display:none
}
```

I found an example i learned from a while back,

credit to jfiddle user mariusc23 - [Hide header on scroll down, show on scroll up](https://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/)

Answer (score 1):

To be perfectly honest I think what is being done in the example is an optical illusion created by the CSS gradient in the background as the user scrolls down.

```
div{

    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow); /* Standard syntax */

}
```

Sorry for hideous colors--taken from external example.

Answer (score 1):

this will hide the header as you scroll down and will show the header as you scroll up.

hope it helps...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
body {
  padding-top: 64px;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.content {
  margin: 10px;
}

.hide-header {
  top: -40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "header">Header content</div>
<div class = "content">
<h1>
Content
</h1>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var currst = 0;
var headerheight = $('.header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(e){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > currst && st > headerheight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('.header').addClass('hide-header');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('.header').removeClass('hide-header');
    }
  }
  currst = st;
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```